# Jar file working when running standalone but doesn't work under Windows service

Tags: java, c#, windows, windows-services, executable-jar

I have a java project, which complied into an executable jar file v-agent-exe.jar. This jar is a log server, log rows is sent to it for processing.
 I can execute it by using this command:

```
`java -jar v-agent-exe.jar -a watch -f config.ini`.
```

After executed, this jar file will create a ServerSocket at port 1235 and listen for incoming data from clients. After data received, the program will process the data and send the result back to the client. When I execute the jar from CMD windows, the processing is working perfect.

Now I am trying to wrap the Jar file as a Windows service (I am using Windows 10). I created a "**Windows service project**" 
in Visual studio like below:
- **Caller** class have **call()** method to execute the jar file using process.
- **AgentService** is the service, which execute **Caller->call()** in another thread.
- **Program** is the main entry to load **AgentService**.

**Caller.cs**

```
public class Caller
{
    static Process proc;

    public Process GetProcess(){
        return proc;        
    }
    public void call() {

        try
        {
            String dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    WorkingDirectory = dir,
                    FileName = "java.exe",
                    Arguments = @"-jar v-agent-exe.jar -a watch -f config.ini",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
            proc.Start();
            while (!proc.StandardError.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = proc.StandardError.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            VAgentService.writeLog("Error when call process: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

AgentService

```
public partial class AgentService : ServiceBase
{
    private string jarPath;
    private string iniPath;
    static Process proc;
    Caller caller;
    public AgentService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        writeLog("On start");
        try
        {
            caller = new Caller();
            writeLog("Prepare to launch thread");
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(caller.call));
            t.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Demo error: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        proc = caller.GetProcess();
        if (proc != null && !proc.HasExited)
        {
            proc.Kill();
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;

        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new AgentService() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

After build the the service project,  I have AgentService.exe.
I install it to my system using:

```
sc create VAgentLogging binpath= %CD%\AgentService.exe depend= lmhosts  start= auto
```

After start the service in service.msc, I can telnet to port "1235" which the java process is listening (I am sure about
    only the jar running in this port). According to the
log of java program, it still can received some part of data but seem like it cannot send back to client or something,
which cause the followed process cannot be done.
I think my problem is: the jar file can executed as standalone but somehow it sucks when wrapped under my service project.
I haven't posted the jar's code yet because I think the error is related to the Windows service project. If you need the java code, please tell me and I will update it here.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is java.exe in your path? Try specifying the full path to the java executable in the "FileName" parameter and see if that helps.